# I got a type error in the Graphql and typescript small project

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typescript-typings, graphql-js

error says: property 'type' is missing in type '{ args: { user_id: { type: GraphQLScalarType<number, number>; }; user_name: { type: GraphQLScalarType<string, string>; }; bank_accounts: { type: GraphQLScalarType<string, string>; }; }; resolve(parent: any, args: any): any; }' but required in type 'GraphQLFieldConfig<any, any, any>'.

11   fields: {addAccountDetails:CREATE_USER},

This is my code link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxA5RDQUshzeppDA3FgXD9l2CL8uIAD0/view?usp=sharing

if you wish to download and install the npm module then you can check. also, I attached my error pictures. Please see that very basic error.

[image]

when I declare my own type account it shows an error in the index.ts file as you can see in the above error says the text.

[image]

Here I created a new Graphql object for an account.

[image]

I want to achieve this in the red text. how can I get it? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make `bank_accounts` string array you should use `GraphQLList` like this:

```
bank_accounts: { type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString) }
```

Also if you plan to store ids in the array it would be better to use `GraphQLID` instead of `GraphQLString`.